# What command would I use to find out how much total space my hard drive has left?

Tags: command-line, disk-usage

What's a single command I can run that shows me the total amount of space free on a hard drive? I don't want to do any math, I just want a command that shows me the total free space on my hard drive.

Comment: You can use `df`

Comment: You can also try 'parted' then 'print free' -- [Source](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12313384/how-to-view-unallocated-free-space-on-a-hard-disk-through-terminal).

Comment: Thanks peeps for the df commands, though those weren't exactly what I was looking for, nor was 'parted'. I was wanting a total via commands, not to have to self total to get a total.

Comment: @DeJeL I think you should amend your question to better explain what you want. I assume you mean the free space totaled for all filesystems on several partitions on a specified hard drive. (Should that include only mounted filesystems? What about partitions mounted via device-mapper? What about logical volumes? Swap space?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use df with the total flag

> --total
>    produce a grand total

```
df --total
```

or

```
df --total -h
```

for human readable output (i.e K,M,G)

This wil produce output such as

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        23G   13G  8.7G  60% /
udev            4.0G  124K  4.0G   1% /dev
tmpfs           4.0G   72K  4.0G   1% /dev/shm
total            31G   13G   17G  44%
```

To only show the total for physical harddisk space(including nfs)

```
df -x tmpfs --total -h

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        23G   13G  8.7G  60% /
total            23G   13G  8.7G  60%
```

Depending on which filetypes you want to exlude (as udev appears to be able to be either `tmpfs` or `devtmpfs`) you can use

```
df -T
Filesystem     Type  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      ext3   23731644 13486576   9039564  60% /
udev           tmpfs   4093900      124   4093776   1% /dev
tmpfs          tmpfs   4093900       72   4093828   1% /dev/shm
                ^
               This column
```

To check the filetypes and then just put the required ones into the `-x` command

Also note that all of these are GNU extensions so you require GNU df.

Comment: That "total" is misleading. You don't have 17G free in your hard drive, only 8.7. The udev and tmpfs filesystems don't count.

Comment: @muru Updated to address your concern.

Comment: `--exclude-type=tmpfs` still shows udev (aka `devtmpfs`).

Comment: @muru doesn't on mine, udev is tmpfs filetype `udev           tmpfs   4093900      124   4093776   1% /dev`

Comment: Odd. It happens to me on Ubuntu 14.04 (`3.13.0-74-generic`) and Arch Linux (`4.4.1-2-ARCH`).

Comment: @muru dunno, I'll add a note though.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`df` command](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_df.htm):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           799M  8.7M  790M   2% /run
/dev/xvda1       50G  6.3G   41G  14% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgmfs           100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs           799M     0  799M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Here, `/dev/xvda1` is my main disk, and it has 41 GB free.

You can also limit the output to only a specific disk or directory:

```
$ df -h /
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       50G  6.3G   41G  14% /
```

Answer (score 1):

`df` (or `df -h` for "human readable" sizes) shows you the filesystem devices, how big are they, how much is used, how much is available, and their mount points in the system.

Take a look [here](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/244) if you want to see some more console commands in your Linux Mint.

Comment: Those other commands from that link helped me with a problem (of self control) I've been having. I loose track of time and stay up all night on my computer, the command will stop that forcefully after the time I allow myself. the command is (sudo) shutdown -h <time_in_minuets>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pydf`. It's an improved version of `df`.
http://linux.die.net/man/1/pydf

It produces an output like this:

```
Filesystem Size Used Avail Use%                 Mounted on
/dev/sdb5   92G  16G   70G 17.9 [##...........] /         
/dev/sdb6  347G  31G  298G  9.0 [#............] /home
```

Comment: Cinnamon does not start with that installed. I want a command that can do this 'cause I'm low on data. So I can't install anything.